# Data Tables get JSON from API without setting "aaData"

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-plugins, datatables

I am using Data Tables and I get my data like it is shown in example

```
$('.data-table').dataTable({
        "bProcessing": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "/api/item/list",
        "aoColumns": [
            { "mData": "Title" },
            { "mData": "Price" }
        ]
});
```

However there is a problem, I need to take all my objects and wrap them in `aaData` for this to work like so

```
[HttpGet]
public dynamic List()
{
    var items = _db.Items.OrderBy(x => x.ID);

    var a = new {
        aaData = items
    };

    return a;
}
```

And this is bad for obvious reason that I need to modify my back-end for this instead of returning plain-old JSON. I've tried setting `aaData` instead of `sAjaxSource` but got errors and it didn't worked. Any ideas on how can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of the property `aaData`, you can tell DataTables to use another property name with the [`sAjaxDataProp`](http://datatables.net/usage/options#sAjaxDataProp) parameter. For example:

```
// Get data from { "data": { "inner": [...] } }
$(document).ready( function() {
  var oTable = $('#example').dataTable( {
    "sAjaxSource": "sources/data.txt",
    "sAjaxDataProp": "data.inner"
  } );
} );
```

Comment: Great, I set `"sAjaxDataProp": ""` and it works now with default JSON output from MVC3 w/o any wrappers. Thanks